# MemSQL: insert ... on duplicate update - finding updated columns

Tags: mysql, singlestore

I'm tracking several hundred objects and pushing their locations and other information into a MemSQL database.

I'm using the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE construct to insert new objects or update existing ones but I'd like to find out which columns have been updated when an object is updated.

I know that I can find out whether the object was inserted, updated or left untouched but I'm trying to find an elegant way of determing which columns have been updated without - ideally - comparing all of them as this needs to optimised for speed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is any direct way to do this in SQL. And no matter what you do, some part of the system is going to have to compute comparisons of all the columns one way or another. So you may be better off doing it directly in your application, that may give you the most options to optimize performance. As far as I know, MemSQL does not compare the old row to the new row, because it doesn't need to, it will just write the new row data in.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess that's the trade off between speed and power. I'll look at redesigning my system - I may be able to push some of the logic into my code without losing too much speed.